# How to re-arranging an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having and issue to rearrange a array, i try most of them.. try to use array_merge, foreach, forloop, while loop etc. but no luck

My concept is not clear i need your help to get an idea how I can change array as per my requirements, Its batter if you give me the concept idea only, i don't required code i try my self first to code it.

Here is the array

```
   Array
    (
      [links] => Array
             (
     [song_name] => Array
             (
                 [0] => AA
                 [1] => BB
                 [2] => CC
                 .....
             )

              [singer_name] => Array
             (
                 [0] => AA
                 [1] => BB
                 [2] => CC
                 .....
             )

              [song_url_320] => Array
             (
                 [0] => AA
                 [1] => BB
                 [2] => CC
                 .....
             )

              [song_url_128] => Array
             (
                 [0] => AA
                 [1] => BB
                 [2] => CC
                 .....
             )
        )

     )
```

I Need to change array like this:

```
Array
(
    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [song_name] => AA
                    [singer_name] => AA
                    [song_url_320] => AA
                    [song_url_128] => AA
                        .....
                )
         [1] => Array
                (
                    [song_name] => BB
                    [singer_name] => BB
                    [song_url_320] => BB
                    [song_url_128] => BB
                        .....
                )
         [2] => Array
                (
                    [song_name] => CC
                    [singer_name] => CC
                    [song_url_320] => CC
                    [song_url_128] => CC
                        .....
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea: loop through all items and combine them into another array

Here is sample code:

```
$inputarray = array(...);

$outputarray = array('links' => array());
foreach ($inputarray['links'] as $k => $v)
    foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
        $outputarray['links'][$k2][$k] = $v2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use for loop like this

```
 foreach($arr['links'] as $k =>$v)
 { 
    foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1) {
         $t[$k1][$k] = $v1; 
      }

 }

 print_r($t);
```

***output***

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [song_name] => AA
            [singer_name] => AA
            [song_url_320] => AA
            [song_url_128] => AA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [song_name] => BB
            [singer_name] => BB
            [song_url_320] => BB
            [song_url_128] => BB
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [song_name] => CC
            [singer_name] => CC
            [song_url_320] => CC
            [song_url_128] => CC
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create yourself an empty array.  Then do a foreach loop for each array in the links array using the index number as the key for the new array.

A little more detail, without showing code.  Do a foreach loop in the links grabbing the alpha index of the array inside links.  Then do a foreach loop on that array inside of links grabbing the numeric index and value of each item.  Then add that in a new links array using the numeric and then alpha key and assigning it the value.

I hope that makes sense to you.  If it doesnt, let me know and I will do some sample code for you.

Comment: Yes... its help, i understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is in a variable $original_array then this would do:

```
$new_array = array('links'=>array());
foreach ($original_array['links'] as $key => $data) foreach ($data as $n => $value) $new_array['links'][$n][$key] = $value;
```